# libGDX font generating bug

Tags: libgdx, fonts

Please, help me with my problem. 
The character is rendering incorrectly.
R symbol looks like N. Also, the symbol ! is not drawn. But this problem was found only on Xiaomi Mi A1. On other devices, such a problem is not detected.
[image]

Font generates like so:

```
public enum Font {

    FONT_REGULAR (Res.FONT_REGULAR_PATH),
    FONT_LIGHT (Res.FONT_LIGHT_PATH),
    RUSSO_ONE_REGULAR (Res.RUSSO_ONE_REGULAR),
    ;

    BitmapFont font;
    String path;

    Font (String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public BitmapFont get (float size) {
        final String FONT_CHARACTERS = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяєїіАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМ" +
                "НОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯЄЇІáabcdeéfghiíjklmnoópqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123" +
                "456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.:;,{}\"´`'<>°©™";
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(path));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = (int) size;
        if (size < 1) parameter.size = 1;
        parameter.characters = FONT_CHARACTERS;
        BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        generator.dispose();
        return font;
    }

}
```

I use [this font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comfortaa).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Some things to try: `parameter.flip = true` (see if it is still weird upside down); `parameter.genMipMaps = true; parameter.minFilter = TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear` (see if MipMap change anything); `parameter.mono = true` (disable font smoothing). These will probably not change anything but if they do maybe they can lead you to a solution.

Comment: @Charanor, thank you! I'll try your recommendations.

Comment: @Charanor your recommendations don't solve this problem. I guess, this problem relates to Android version (8.0). I tried to launch my game on Nokia 6 (with same android version) and this problem also appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution!

I just added this:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(2048);
```

So, full code looks like so:

```
public BitmapFont get (float size) {
    final String FONT_CHARACTERS = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяєїіАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМ" +
            "НОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯЄЇІáabcdeéfghiíjklmnoópqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123" +
            "456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.:;,{}\"´`'<>°©™";

    FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(2048);

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(path));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size = (int) size;
    if (size < 1) parameter.size = 1;
    parameter.characters = FONT_CHARACTERS;
    BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    generator.dispose();
    return font;
}
```